# Get selected records in linq union from two different tables

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have two tables, `UserNotifications` and `GlobalNotifications`.  I need to `Union` these two tables together and date order them to retrieve a users notification history.  This is the working query I currently have:

```
var q = db.UserNotifications.Where(c => c.UserID == forUser.ScirraUserID)
    .Select(c => new {c.ID, type = "u", date = c.FirstDate})
    .Union(db.GlobalNotifications.Select(c => new {c.ID, type = "g", date = c.Date}))
    .OrderBy(c => c.date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

Problem is, I can't work out of it's possible to return the `UserNotifications` and `GlobalNotifications` records in the results as supposed to just their type and ID, which will require another query to the database to retrieve.

Comment: You can join them with the original tables with the anonymous type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter am a bit lost, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't understand the `Union` since both can never be the same, they have a different types. So you can use `Concat` instead of `Union`. According to the join, you could join them via `Id`+`Date` with the appropriate tables, one join with `UserNotifications` where `type = "u"` and one with `GlobalNotifications` on id and date where `type = "g"`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm getting a bit stuck here, I can't work out how to concat the two tables and return the records from both

Comment: i'm not sure if you can do it in one query since both are different tables so different types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public enum NotificationType { User, Global }

public class mytype {
public int ID {get;set;}
public NotificationType type {get;set;}
public DateTime FirstDate {get;set;}
public UserNotification un {get;set;}
public GlobalNotification gn {get;set;}
}

var q = db.UserNotifications.Where(c => c.UserID == forUser.ScirraUserID)
    .Select(c => new mytype {c.ID, type = NotificationType.User, date = c.FirstDate, un=c, gn=null})
    .Union(db.GlobalNotifications.Select(c => new mytype {c.ID, type = NotificationType.Global, date = c.Date, un=null, gn=c }))
    .OrderBy(c => c.date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

or you can just test to see which of un,gn is null and skip the type like:

```
var q = db.UserNotifications.Where(c => c.UserID == forUser.ScirraUserID)
    .Select(c => new mytype {c.ID, date = c.FirstDate, un=c, gn=null})
    .Union(db.GlobalNotifications.Select(c => new mytype {c.ID, date = c.Date, un=null, gn=c }))
    .OrderBy(c => c.date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

Or if both UserNotification and GlobalNotification both have a common ancestor (Notification) or interface (INotification?), then use and cast to that perhaps.

If you are using LINQ2SQL, then you may need to do this:

```
var q = db.UserNotifications
    .Where(c => c.UserID == forUser.ScirraUserID)
    .ToList()
    .Select(c => new mytype {
        c.ID, 
        type = NotificationType.User, 
        date = c.FirstDate, 
        un=c, 
        gn=null})
    .Concat(
        db.GlobalNotifications
            .Select(c => new mytype {
                c.ID, 
                type = NotificationType.Global, 
                date = c.Date, 
                un=null, 
                gn=c })
            .ToList())
    .OrderBy(c => c.date)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

Try 2:

```
var q1 = db.UserNotifications
    .Where(c => c.UserID == forUser.ScirraUserID)
    .OrderBy(c => c.FirstDate)
    .Select(c => new mytype {
        c.ID, 
        type = NotificationType.User, 
        date = c.FirstDate, 
        un=c, 
        gn=null})
    .Take(skip+take)
    .ToList();
var q2=db.GlobalNotifications
    .OrderBy(c => c.Date)
    .Select(c => new mytype {
        c.ID, 
        type = NotificationType.Global, 
        date = c.Date, 
        un=null, 
        gn=c })
    .Take(skip+take)
    .ToList();
var r=q1.Concat(q2)
    .OrderBy(c => c.FirstDate)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(take);
```

Comment: Both methods throw the error `Types in Union or Concat are constructed incompatibly.`

Comment: Try `.Concat` instead of `.Union` -- If this is LINQ2SQL, then it may be a problem with the implementation.  Updating answer with a bad solution.

Comment: Or error `Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.`

Comment: You get that error on the new code?  It shouldn't be using LINQ to SQL at that point.  It's a bad solution anyhow cause it won't be very scalable as it it will potentially read a lot of data from the database and then throw it away.

Comment: Updated again.  Fixed pagination issues.  It now takes (skip+take) from each place, converts to objects, then does the concatination in LINQ over Objects and then does a final skip and take.  This will perform worse as you go deeper into the pagination, but should work ok for the first few pages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's correct but as you mention has a performance issue with deep pagination.  Marking as correct, but will be using my original solution but fetching each record. independantly.

Comment: You could use your first query to retrieve the IDs and then use the IDs to retrieve the correct records.  It'd be 3 queries then without the deep pagination performance issues.